# Active Directory DNS probelm

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

---

I have following scenario.

Windows 2008 R2 base Active Directory DC (DC1), which is hosting DNS+﻿ DHCP too. (previously it was on windows 2003 32bit, i migrated it last year on 2008 r2 64bit). Also there are two ADC's , one with Windows 2003 (DC2), and second with Windows 2008r2 (DC3).

The problem is that when the DC reboot, DNS donot work for about 20-25 minutes. When i try to do nslookup on client or even on the dc , it gives me unknown server, and no resolving done. Active directory and users groups also not open. After 15-20 minutes everything starts to work fine. in DC LAN  properties,  I have preferred dns server pointing to DC itself, and secondary to other ADC.
I have also tried to do nslookup on other ADC's but they also donot respond. When the main DC start working, ADC also works fine. So the concept of having ADC in case of disaster is also not applying :(

I have tried restarting the netlogon service, dns service, but no use. The hardware is very good as its IBM Xseries machine with modern hardware so resource is not an issue here i am sure. Also

I have no specific customized security or group policy in place. Only Symantec Antivirus is installed (no network protection) , I have tried to disable it, but no gain.

What else to check ?

Comment: `1.` Stop calling them ADC's. They're just DC's. There's no primary, secondary, alternate, PDC or BDC. They're all DC's. `2.` As Ryan pointed out in his answer, a DC/DNS should point to another DC/DNS for DNS first, then itself.

Answer (score 3):

> Also there are two DCs
>
> I have preferred dns server pointing to DC itself, and secondary to other ADC

Each domain controller should point at the other DC *first* as its preferred DNS resolver, and it should point at itself (127.0.0.1) second (or third if you have 3 DCs, etc..)  If a domain controller is configured to look at itself *first* for DNS, you will experience considerable delays in boot times as AD DS and DNS timeout because of a circular dependency during bootup.  (Active Directory needs DNS to start, but DNS won't start until AD is ready.)

Comment: Ok I have added primary dns pointing to other (dc) dns server. I will post update once DC is next rebooted.